# I just started coding and I got this error undefined reference to winmain@16 in vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

this is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("I just started");
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the error

```
PS E:\coding> cd "e:\coding\" ; if ($?) { gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile } ; if ($?) { .\tempCodeRunnerFile }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Run preferably [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with all warnings and debug information, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile`. BTW, consider installing some Linux distribution (perhaps [Debian](http://debian.org/) or [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/) ...) on your computer. It is much more developer friendly than Windows.

Comment: Please indent your question correctly so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64274376/edit) it: four spaces before every source code line. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your editor (e.g. [VisualStudioCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)), the documentation of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).  On Linux your code compiles well

Comment: Windows is different than "normal" systems, and it needs a special "main" function. And please use your favorite search engine to find clues.

Comment: most likely your telling the project definition that you are creating the wrong kind of project.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that "YOU DIDN'T save YOUR FILE", first save your cpp file then enter the command (g++ file.cpp) or run it.
Usually, this error occurs when file was not saved.

so click anywhere on your file and press ctrl+s to save it again,
NOW YOUR ERROR GOT FIXXED, ......................

Comment: related: [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/11107541)